# How can I check if mysql table column even exists?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I check if mysql table field even exists ?

The column name is 'price' and I need to see if it exists.

Haven't understood really how the 'EXISTS' works...

Any examples or ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: You mean column named "price"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In PHP:

```
$fields = mysql_list_fields('database_name', 'table_name');
$columns = mysql_num_fields($fields);
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {$field_array[] = mysql_field_name($fields, $i);}

if (!in_array('price', $field_array))
{
$result = mysql_query('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD price VARCHAR(10)');
}
```

This should also help you:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = ‘TEST’ AND COLUMN_NAME = ‘TEST_DATE’)
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE TEST ADD TEST_DATE DATETIME
END
```

Or you can do:

```
Show columns from table like 'string';
```

There has been a similar question posed on [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033/how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-sql-table) before.

Comment: does `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` works in MySQL?

Comment: @Benubird: No, what are you talking about? I'm not going to change my answer from 3 years ago.

Comment: mysql extension is deprecated. Answer should be updated.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Price')
BEGIN
    -- do something, e.g.
    -- ALTER TABLE TEST ADD PRICE DECIMAL
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it in PHP:

```
$chkcol = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 1"); 
$mycol = mysql_fetch_array($chkcol); 
if(isset($mycol['price'])) 
  echo "Column price exists! Do something...";
```

Comment: No, answers to old questions help those of looking. Keep adding better answers to old questions I say.  If we are not supposed to "resurrect" old questions, then mods should not close repeated questions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way is to do:

```
select price from your_table limit 1
```

If you get an error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'price' in 'field list'
```

then it does not exists.

Comment: what kind of error do you mean? How can I check if it's an error then ?

Comment: See my answer above for PHP example

Answer (score 1):

I found this very useful. It will list all the tables that has that column name.

```
SELECT table_name, 
       column_name 
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  column_name LIKE '%the_column_name%'
```

Answer (score 1):

well here is a function to check out if a particular column exists or not.

```
public function detect_column($my_db, $table, $column)
{
    $db = mysql_select_db($my_db); //select the database
    $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table LIKE '$column'"; //query
    $result = mysql_query($sql);                     //querying
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)        //checks the absence of column
        echo "column $column doesn't exist !";
        // write your code here! 
    else
        echo "column $column exists!";
}
```

well if you are designing a frame work, then this function may come to your aid. This function checks for the presence of column when $flag is set to '1' and absence of column when $flag is set to '0'.

```
public function detect_column($my_db, $table, $column, $flag)
{
    $this->select_db($my_db); //select the database
    $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table LIKE '$column'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == $flag)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get a description of all the column in your table.

`desc your_table;`

Answer (score 0):

I just done something like this using this function for Wordpress, this for update tables that having new chnages on it

```
public function alterTable() {

    $table_name = $this->prefix . $this->tables['name'];

    $select = "select * from `{$table_name}` where 0=0 limit 1;";
    $query = $this->db->get_results($select, ARRAY_A);


    if (isset($query[0]) && !key_exists('adv', $query[0])) {
        $sql = "ALTER TABLE `{$table_name}` ADD `me` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL ;";
        $this->db->query($sql);
    }
```

}